# Nginx Internal Error by adding a new proxy host

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, containers, nginx-reverse-proxy, synology

I am new with Nginx Proxy Manager and I am running NPM in a docker container and it is running smoothly, but I am not able to create new SSL certificates. When I try to add a new proxy host and choose for SSL > Request a new SSL certificate with Let's Encrypt and press save I get the message: Internal Error.

I cannot find the issue here why its not saving. What am I doing wrong?

I use to create Lets encrypt certificate from out my NAS but I decide to switch over to Nginx Proxy Manager in combination with Authentik. Till now I am only having issues with NPM with creating Proxy Hosts and SSL certificates. Its leading me to the Internal Error message.
For example I am trying to point one of my containers like; Filebot, Dozzle, Portainer etc. and its not working properly